# InfluxDB - Getting metrics like write per second using chronograf

Tags: metrics, influxdb, chronograf

We are trying to  plot metrics like Write per second for a measurement in an Influx DB database using TICK Stack. We are hosting influxDB on Ubuntu and have followed the instruction in  the following  link

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-monitor-system-metrics-with-the-tick-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

We are trying to create a dashboard for getting Write per second for a measurement in an Influx DB database. However we could not find any corresponding documentation.

Has any one done this... Can anyone point us to the necessary documentation

Thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `non-negative derivative` is what you're looking for.

The documentation for that InfluxDB function can be found at https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/latest/query_language/functions/#non-negative-derivative.

According to the docs there, `non-negative derivative... [r]eturns the non-negative rate of change between subsequent field values. Non-negative rates of change include positive rates of change and rates of change that equal zero.`